# 589/5000 How do I configure in realurl a speaking URL for the tx_news date filter?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, realurl, tx-news

How do I configure in the extension realurl a destination page for the date menu from tx_news.

Currently my realurl looks as follows:

http://pastebin.com/SyEzttqD

The links are output in the form:

MyDomain.tdl / nwes.html? Tx_news_pi1% 5BoverwriteDemand% 5D% 5Byear% 5D = 2017 & tx_news_pi1% 5BoverwriteDemand% 5D% 5Bmonth% 5D = 03 & cHash = b671ba816868bf63e419eeacacc74175

The goal would be:

Mydomain.tdl / date-filter / year / month.html

The rest of the tx_news configuration seems to be running.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `realurl_conf.php` and delete the URL Data in TYPO3 afterwards:

```
'postVarSets' => array(
    '_DEFAULT' => array(
        'controller' => array(
            'date-filter' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][year]',
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][month]',
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
)
```